# How can I get the real IP address of Client behind F5 loadbalancer with Java socket

Tags: java, sockets, f5, big-ip

I am developing a Java application. The client sends socket request to the sever after the F5 loadbalancer. The server should record the IP address of the socket request. How can I get the real IP address of the client instead of the IP addreess of the F5.

Comment: If the load balancer doensn't add the original ip as a header then you're out of luck

Comment: @MichaelWiles You don't always _need_ to add anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using *SNAT*, your *Virtual Server* must be configured with an *HTTP Profile*, and this profile must have the *Insert X-Forwarded-For* enabled. As simple as that.

Of course this means the server must be able to use this header.

If the loadbalancer doesn't use any SNAT, you would already see the client's IP.